# ERROR ng has unexpectedly closed exit code 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

I tried to update Angular and capacitor to latest version, but now when I am firing ionic capacitor run ios -l --e its throwing error '[ERROR] ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code 3).'.

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^6.1.10",
"@angular/common": "~10",
"@angular/core": "~10",
"@angular/forms": "~10",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~10",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10",
"@angular/router": "~10",
"@capacitor/android": "^3.0.0",
"@capacitor/core": "^3.0.0",
"@capacitor/ios": "^3.0.0",
"@ionic-native/app-availability": "^5.33.1",
"@ionic-native/core": "^5.33.1",
"@ionic-native/email-composer": "^5.33.1",
"@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^5.33.1",
"@ionic-native/launch-navigator": "^5.33.1",
"@ionic-native/photo-viewer": "^5.33.1",
"@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.33.1",
"@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.33.1",
"@ionic/angular": "^5.6.8",
"@ionic/storage": "^2.3.1",
"cordova-plugin-actionsheet": "^2.3.3",
"cordova-plugin-appavailability": "^0.4.2",
"cordova-plugin-dialogs": "^2.0.2",
"cordova-plugin-email-composer": "^0.9.2",
"cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^4.0.0",
"cordova-plugin-ionic": "5.4.7",
"cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^6.0.0",
"cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4",
"core-js": "^2.6.12",
"hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
"jetifier": "^1.6.8",
"moment": "^2.29.1",
"natives": "^1.1.6",
"ngx-pipes": "^2.7.5",
"ngx-socket-io": "^3.3.1",
"rxjs": "^6.6.7",
"time-ago-pipe": "^1.3.2",
"tslib": "^1.14.1",
"uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator": "^5.0.5",
"zone.js": "~0.9.1"
```

},
`"devDependencies": { "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.29", "@angular/cli": "^12.0.3", "@angular/compiler": "~10", "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10", "@angular/language-service": "~10", "@capacitor/cli": "^3.0.0", "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.3.3", "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.2.4", "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8", "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.9", "@types/node": "~8.9.4", "codelyzer": "^5.2.2", "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0", "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1", "karma": "~4.1.0", "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0", "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1", "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1", "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.6.0", "protractor": "^5.4.4", "ts-node": "~7.0.0", "tslint": "~5.15.0", "typescript": "^3.9.5" },`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you check the upgrade guide for capacitor ?

https://capacitorjs.com/docs/updating/3-0

There might be some compatibility problem with plugins

Comment: Yes, it was related to Capacitor versioning